# Read Excel file from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, exceljs

I am trying to read a spreadsheet uploaded to Google Storage from Nodejs App running on App Engine.

The function offered by @google-cloud/storage package in Nodejs is createReadStream(). I am pass this stream to the Exceljs object.

The code is as follows:

```
const blob = bucket.file(req.file.originalname);
const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream();
blobStream.on('finish', () => {

    let readStream = storage.bucket(bucket.name).file(blob.name).createReadStream();

    let returnString = '';

    const workbook = new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookReader();
        var options = {
        entries: "emit",
        sharedStrings: "cache",
        worksheets: "emit"
    };

    workbook.read(readStream, options);

    workbook.on('worksheet', function (worksheet) {
        console.log("worksheet", worksheet.name);
        worksheet.on('row', function (row) {
            if(row.values.length > 0){
                console.log(" row.values", row.values[1]);
                returnString += row.values[1] + " ";
            }
        });

        worksheet.on('close', function () {
            console.log("worksheet close");
        });

        worksheet.on('finished', function () {
            console.log("worksheet finished");
            res.send(returnString);
        });
    });
});

blobStream.end(req.file.buffer);
```

Is workbook.read(readStream, options) getting the right readStream?

As I am getting the following error mentioning this:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Could not recognise input
2019-07-07 20:35:09 default[20190708t020308]      at module.exports._getStream (/srv/node_modules/exceljs/dist/es5/stream/xlsx/workbook-reader.js:58:11)
2019-07-07 20:35:09 default[20190708t020308]      at module.exports.read (/srv/node_modules/exceljs/dist/es5/stream/xlsx/workbook-reader.js:79:37)
2019-07-07 20:35:09 default[20190708t020308]      at Pumpify.blobStream.on (/srv/app.js:80:14)
2019-07-07 20:35:09 default[20190708t020308]      at Pumpify.emit (events.js:198:13)
2019-07-07 20:35:09 default[20190708t020308]      at finishMaybe (/srv/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:630:14)
2019-07-07 20:35:09 default[20190708t020308]      at afterWrite (/srv/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:492:3)
2019-07-07 20:35:09 default[20190708t020308]      at onwrite (/srv/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:483:7)
2019-07-07 20:35:09 default[20190708t020308]      at Pumpify.WritableState.onwrite (/srv/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:180:5)
2019-07-07 20:35:09 default[20190708t020308]      at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
2019-07-07 20:35:09 default[20190708t020308]      at Pumpify.emit (events.js:198:13)
2019-07-07 20:35:09 default[20190708t020308]      at Pumpify.Duplexify.uncork (/srv/node_modules/duplexify/index.js:77:50)
```

Comment: Looking at the source of the exceljs code here ... https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/blob/master/lib/stream/xlsx/workbook-reader.js   it seems that your stream is not an instance of "Stream.Readable".  This would be my first test ... make sure that your readStream feels good when it is to be used.

Comment: Earlier I was uploading the file to cloud storage and then reading it from cloud function, but then now I am reading it directly from buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload a file using multer and cloud storage, the "process" it's:
You have a file in a buffer by multer, and then, with this buffer, you writes a file in cloud storage, so you can  take advantage of this just reading the multer buffer with exceljs.

```
const Stream = require('stream'); //Stream is a node resourse
const blob = bucket.file(req.file.originalname);
const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream();
blobStream.on('finish', () => {
  // ToDo when the file has uploaded in storage
})
let workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
let stream = new Stream.Readable(); 
stream.push(req.file.buffer); // using multer buffer
stream.push(null);
workbook.xlsx.read(stream).then((workbook)=> {
  // ToDo with excel file readed
})
```